# for loop through inputs and return the value of each input

Tags: javascript, express

I have an express app, In my EJS file I am looping though my data to create 5 different inputs type hidden, each one with a different value.

I need, from my javaScript file to loop through all the inputs selecting them by class name and to extract the value of each input. I have tried several options with no success.

This is have I have:

This is in my html

```
<% course.content.forEach(function(content, i) { %>
  <input class="editCourseContent" type="hidden" value="<%= course.content[i] %>">
<% }); %>
```

this is my JavaScript

```
hiddenInputEdit = document.getElementsByClassName('.editCourseContent');

includeEditTags();

function includeEditTags(){
  for(var i = 0; i < hiddenInputEdit.length; i++){
    alert(hiddenInputEdit[i].val());
  }
}
```

Comment: `.value`, not `.val()` - And it is EITHER `hiddenInputEdit = document.getElementsByClassName('editCourseContent');` OR `hiddenInputEdit = document.querySelectorAll('.editCourseContent');`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using jquery `val()` will not work. So Change `hiddenInputEdit[i].val()` to `hiddenInputEdit[i].value`

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('.editCourseContent'); would not return jQuery objects, in fact the dot makes it not return anything at all

Comment: @brk - Apologies on that other answer: MDN is right. The spec is a bit misleading because `Object.values` uses [EnumerateOwnPropertyNames](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerableownpropertynames), which uses [[OwnPropertyNames]], which provides order -- but then in the next step it explicitly says it rearranges them to match the (unspecified) implementation-specific order of `for-in`. *sigh*. So it **was** a dupe of the canonical, my brain just took a holiday there for a bit. Sorry. :-)